# Why do these two if statements have different meanings?

Tags: javascript

Let's take the code

```
 var dumb = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

 for (var x = 0; x < dumb.length; x++){
    if (dumb[x] % 2) {
       console.log(dumb[x]);
    }
}
```

In the above program, it produces (1,3,5)
But if the if statement was: (if dumb[x] % 2 === 0), it produces (2,4,6)

Why Does

```
    if (dumb[x] % 2)
```

and

```
    if (dumb[x] % 2 === 0)
```

produce difference results?

Answer (score 2):

In a conditional statement in JavaScript `0` is `false` and all other numbers are `true`.

```
if (dumb[x] % 2) // if the numbers is even, it's false because the remainder is 0.
```

and

```
if (dumb[x] % 2 === 0) 
//if even it's true, because the remainder 0 which is what you are comparing it to.
```

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing the output of the modulo operator, vs the output of a boolean expression.

```
dumb[x] % 2
```

works out to a number, while

```
dumb[x] % 2 === 0
```

works out to a boolean, true or false.

If the first expression works out to 0, it'll be falsey, otherwise it'll  be truthy.